# Gitlab and Cypress - error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, cypress

I am trying to get Cypress e2e tests to run with gitlab runners and have run into a host of issues. My pipeline has 3 steps: install dependencies, run build, run tests.

Here is my current config:

```
image: node:14.0.0

variables:
  API_BASE_URL: https://test.local.mysite.io/api
  API_BASE_URL: https://test.local.mysite.io/api
  npm_config_cache: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm'
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress'

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - cache/Cypress

stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test

install:
  stage: install
  cache:
    key: 'e2eDeps'
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - cache/Cypress/
  script:
    - npm i

build:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - install
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_success

tests:
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run start:ci &
    - npm run test
```

Here are the scripts in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
    "start:ci": "serve --no-clipboard --listen ${PORT:-3000}",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test && npm run test:jest && npm run test:cypress",
    "test:ci": "npx start-test start:ci http://localhost:3000 test",
    "test:cypress": "ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 cypress run --headless",
    "test:cypress-open": "cypress open",
    "test:jest": "jest",
    "test:jest-watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
  },
```

What I would ideally like to happen is the first step to run the installation of all the dependencies and the following steps to use those dependencies to do the build or run the tests. So far I have managed to get the first two steps working (install & build) but the 3rd one keeps failing on the Cypress tests (`npm run test:cypress`)

I first of all got this error when running the tests without the `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1` flag:

> Error: spawn Xvfb ENOENT

After looking into the issue it seems that Cypress requires some system dependencies to be able to run it's tests as detailed [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#System-requirements). I am unsure if it is even possible to install these system dependencies in Gitlab runners so I tried going with another approach I found online which mentioned adding the `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1` flag when running the tests. It was successful in getting of the error however I am then presented with a different error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I can not find any helpful answers anywhere about the above error unfortunately. It seems the scripts i'm trying to run are fairly basic/ standard so i'm unsure why they are failing. Could someone please show me where i've gone wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the missing libxshmfence.so.1 library error on trying to run Cypress. I tried following various suggestions found under related questions on stack overflow to install different dependencies, all without success. Finally I discovered that the reason I was getting this error is that I was on a 32 bit Debian VM, and only 64 bit is supported. I spun up a 64 bit Ubuntu desktop VM using Vagrant and the problem did not occur there.